Counting number of orders per unique person
Is there a more elegant way to perform calculations of total number of orders per person?
My dataset contains a list of people , date when order was placed, order method, product description. I don't have an unique order id column (which would make my life easier). I have 1 order per row.
In my sql code i assign a row number to each order in 1rst nested query, then I count max number of orders per person in the 2nd nested query.
At the end, I perform calculations to see how many people placed 1 order only, 2 orders only, etc.
select distinct
max_nbr_of_devices_ordered
, count(distinct prsn_id) as numer
from ( select distinct
        prsn_id
        , max(nbr_of_devices_ordered) as max_nbr_of_devices_ordered
        from ( select distinct
               prsn_id
               , Row_Number() Over (PARTITION BY prsn_id ORDER BY order_date, product_desc ASC) AS nbr_of_devices_ordered
               from hsd_orders
               ) as a
        group by 1
        ) as b
group by 1


Haven't  had my tea yet, but something like select num_orders, count(pers_id) from (select pers_id, count (*) as num_orders from <table> group by pers_id)  T group by num_orders should work.  Sample data and desired result would be very helpful.

yes that works, thank you

this answer provided by Andrew worked:
select 
order_count
, count(distinct prsn_id) as numer
from (select distinct prsn_id, count (*) as order_count from hsd_orders group by prsn_id)  T 
group by 1 


the sub-select select distinct prsn_id does not need distinct, as the group by does this effect. so select prsn_id, count (*) as order_count from hsd_orders group by prsn_id or select prsn_id, count (*) as order_count from hsd_orders group by 1

which then means the count count(distinct prsn_id) also does not need distinct, as there is only disinct id's already.

As noted in comments the distincts can be dropped as they are not doing any work here:
select 
  order_count
  ,count(prsn_id) as numer
from (select prsn_id, count (*) as order_count from hsd_orders group by 1) 
group by 1 

works thus for some fake data:
with hsd_orders(ord_id, prsn_id, date) as (
    select * from values
    (1, 1, '2024-09-25'),
    (2, 2, '2024-09-25'),
    (3, 2, '2024-09-26'),
    (4, 3, '2024-09-25'),
    (5, 3, '2024-09-26'),
    (6, 3, '2024-09-26'),
    (7, 4, '2024-09-26'),
    (8, 4, '2024-09-25')
)
select 
  order_count
  ,count(prsn_id) as numer
from (select prsn_id, count (*) as order_count from hsd_orders group by 1) 
group by 1 

we get:



ORDER_COUNT
NUMER




1
1


2
2


3
1



But it can be more simpler, because we are not using the person id's we do not need to carry them, just to throw them away.
select 
  order_count
  ,count(1) as numer
from (
  select count (*) as order_count 
  from hsd_orders 
  group by prsn_id
) 
group by 1 


If you really want to avoid a subquery
select distinct 
       count(*) as num_orders, 
       count(prsn_id) over (partition by num_orders) as num_people
from hsd_orders 
group by prsn_id
order by num_orders;

